# Transformation of an equation into a function

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Since one of my exams is getting closer and I still can't understand a certain problem, I need your help. 
I simply can't understand how my teacher did following transformation:

$$\frac{p - a}{v \cdot n_e} = 1-n \iff p(n,n_e) = (a + v \cdot n_e) - v \cdot n_e \cdot n$$

Could anyone explain it to me how she got from an equation to a function?

Edit: simply solving the formula for $p = \ldots$ is the exact solution. But where do the brackets $(n,n_e)$ come from?

Comment: Just take $n=x$ and $n_e=y$, he just wrote $p$ as a function of $x$ and $y$ i.e. $p=f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{p - a}{v \cdot n_e} = 1-n$$

and multiplying both sides by $v \cdot n_e$

$$p-a = v \cdot n_e-n(v \cdot n_e)$$

and then

$$p= (a+v \cdot n_e)-n(v \cdot n_e)$$

finally, assuming $n$ and $n_e$ as variables, we can define the function

$$p(n,n_e):= (a+v \cdot n_e)-n(v \cdot n_e)$$

Note that the parentheses $(n,n_e)$ are used as a symbol to declare the variables for the function. In this case we are assuming $n$ and $n_e$ as variables while $a$ and $v$ are parameters.

Comment: Yes, I understand the calculation and the solving for p = ...  
But can you simply make up a function by just adding brackets?

Comment: @koapsi The brakets are used to declare the variables for the function. In this case we are assuming $n$ and $n_e$ as variables while $a$ and $v$ are parameters.

Comment: Alrighty, If it's so easy then i understand everything. Thank you for your help

Comment: @koapsi Yes of course! Weel done, nothing difficult here :)